# can't configure Watson OpenScale on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-openscale

I can’t create APIClient for watson openscale.
I get message:

```
AuthorizationError: You are not authorized to access AI OpenScale instance ***
```

I am following the notebook below and stopped at ‘Configure OpenScale’ part:

```
https://github.com/IBM/watson-openscale-samples/blob/main/IBM%20Cloud/WML/notebooks/binary/spark/Watson%20OpenScale%20and%20Watson%20ML%20Engine.ipynb
```

I am failing on :

```
wos_client = APIClient(service_url='https://api.aiopenscale.cloud.ibm.com', service_instance_id='***', authenticator=IAMAuthenticator(apikey=CLOUD_API_KEY))
```

Will be grateful for any help

Comment: And that's where you put in your API key? Please add details to your question.What API key are you using? If it is a variable, did you set it?

Comment: @data_henrik - yes, I set api key as CLOUD_API_KEY variable. It's a standard ibm cloud api key generated in manage -> IAM -> API keys -> Create an IBM API key. This key works just fine in the same code,  few lines above,  on other cloud service Watson MAchine Learning.

Comment: Why is your code about for APIClient different to the one in the linked notebook? Have you tried it like in the notebook, create the authenticator, then pass it?

Comment: Sure, I tried the original code and it did not work. Sorry, I should have put the original line into the question.

Answer (score 1):

data_henrik, thanks for your investigation.

It turned out the default code works fine for Watson OpenScale sitting in Dallas region of IBM Cloud. For my instance of WOS sitting in Frankfurt, I had wrong service_url and missing url parameter.
The proper configuration is following:

```
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey=CLOUD_API_KEY, url = "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token")
wos_client = APIClient(authenticator=authenticator, service_instance_id = "*****", 
service_url="https://eu-de.api.aiopenscale.cloud.ibm.com")
```

I have refreshed authenticator url, the old one stopped working.